# Método recursivo para apresentar a representação de um número inteiro em uma base

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursão

Escreva um método recursivo `base()` que aceite um inteiro não negativo `n` e um inteiro positivo `1 < b < 10` e apresente a representação base `b` do inteiro `n`.

```
>>> base(0, 2)
0
>>> base(1, 2)
1
>>> base(10, 2)
1010
>>> base(10, 3) 
1 0 1
```

Eu apenas consegui fazer uma solução não-recursiva:

```
def base(n,b):
    restos = []
    quo = b+1
    if 1 < b <10:
        if n >=b:
            while quo >= b:
                resto = n % b
                quo = n // b
                n = quo
                restos.append(resto)
            return quo, restos[::-1]

print(base(72,2))
```

Como fazer a solução recursiva em Python?

Answer (score 3):

```
def conv(num,b):
    convStr = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    if num<b:
        return convStr[num]
    else:
        return conv(num//b,b) + convStr[num%b]
print (conv(4,2)) #will just return 100
```

Comment: Ficou bem bacana isso aí, hein?  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Para converter até a base 10, daria para fazer assim:

```
def base(n, b):
    if n == 0 or b == 10:
        return n

    return (n % b) + 10 * base(n // b, b)
```

Se o número for zero ou a base for 10, não há nenhuma conta a fazer, então retorne o próprio número.

Caso contrário, pegue o resto da divisão do número pela base (`n % b`) e some com 10 multiplicado pela conversão do número dividido pela base. Confuso? Vamos ver um exemplo:

- Converter 3 para a base 2: `base(3, 2)`

  - 3 não é igual a zero e a base é 2, não entra no `if`
  - retorna `3 % 2` (ou seja, `1`) somado com `10 * base(3 // 2, 2)`
  - `base(3 // 2, 2)` é o mesmo que `base(1, 2)`

    - 1 não é igual a zero e a base é 2, não entra no `if`
    - retorna `1 % 2` (ou seja, `1`) somado com `10 * base(1 // 2, 2)`
    - `base(1 // 2, 2)` é o mesmo que `base(0, 2)`

      - como `n` é zero, entra no `if` e retorna o próprio número (no caso, zero)
    - `10 * base(1 // 2, 2)` é `10 * 0`, que resulta em zero. Somado com `1 % 2`, dá `1`
  - `10 * base(3 // 2, 2)` é `10 * 1`, que é igual a `10`. Somado com `3 % 2`, resulta em `11`
- a função retorna `11`, que é a representação de `3` na base 2.

**Obs:** Só lembrando que na verdade o valor retornado é o próprio número 11 (onze) e ele está na base 10. O que fizemos foi gerar um valor na base 10 cujos dígitos são os mesmos que seriam se o número original (no caso, `3`) estivesse na base 2. Então não adianta usar esse `11` achando que seu valor será `3`.

---

Para bases maiores que 10, não tem como fazer só com essas contas, pois alguns símbolos usados passam a ser letras. Neste caso você teria que usar uma lista pré-definida de símbolos e concatenar as strings (em vez de somar e multiplicar para construir o número), tal como foi feito na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/432255/112052) (que aceita até a base 36).

No fundo, a outra resposta usa a mesma lógica, a diferença é que ela concatena strings, adicionando novos dígitos no final, enquanto a solução acima multiplica por 10 para "empurrar" os dígitos para a esquerda.